# Is "policy maker" one word or two?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, grammaticality

Is it correct to write "policy maker" in two words? It is unclear to me whether it should be written as: policy maker or policymaker or policy-maker.

Comment: All three are correct, but you should be consistent within the same document.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=policymaker%2C+policy+maker&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "policymaker" and "policy maker" have currency, and either can be used.

By binding the words into a compound word, you indicate that you view this as a particular role, or job title, and not just a person who makes policy.  Splitting the word would allow you consider people that make more than just policies.

> After three years as a backbench MP, John became a policymaker when he became a Junior minister.

> Policy and proposal makers should consider ethics.

But in 99% of use, it is just a matter of style and preference.

Answer (score -3):

"Policymaker" is a single word.   There is also some use with hyphenation, but you should use a single word.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/policymaker

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/policymaker

Comment: _Our conclusion was that the IPCC report provides the best summary of prevailing scientific opinion on climate change currently available to policy makers._ Tim Yeo, Conservative MP, 20 Nov 2014  - Hansard (UK Parliament proceedings)

Comment: Are you claiming that both of the OED and MW entries I posted here are incorrect, because you found a single transcript where it is written as two words?

Comment: Career Guidance - A Handbook for Policy Makers - This joint publication of the OECD and the European Commission gives policy makers practical tools to tackle weaknesses in many countries' career guidance systems.

Comment: Please provide an authoritative source that supports your claim if so.   (If you are not, why the downvote?)

Comment: Evaluation for policy makers - A straightforward guide (The Scottish Government)

Comment: You are not answering my question.  Are both OED and MW entries incorrect?

Comment: Handbook for policy makers  on the rights of the child  in the digital environment (Committee of Ministers of the Council of Europe)

Comment: Please do not spam use examples in chat, and provide an authoritative source to support your claim.

Comment: The dictionary provides evidence that "policymaker" as a single word *may* be used.  It doesn't provide evidence that it *must* be used. Yours and Michael's examples suggest that "policymaker" and "policy maker" both have currency, and you could edit your answer to reflect that.  A good thing to add is whether there is any difference in meaning.  For example both "blackbird" and "black bird" are correct, but have a different meaning.